# Whenever I submit the first query, I always get an "error" with Gradio. But subsequent queries work fine. Why?

Tags: python, gradio

I'm following the basic Gradio interface from the [Gradio documentation](https://www.gradio.app/docs/interface):

```
import gradio as gr

def greet(name):
    return "Hello " + name #+ "!" +a

demo = gr.Interface(fn=greet, inputs="text", outputs="text")

demo.launch()
```

When I go to the UI via Chrome (http://127.0.0.1:7860/), whenever I submit the first query right after stating the server, I always get an "error":

[image]

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fra\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\gradio\routes.py", line 534, in predict
    output = await route_utils.call_process_api(
  File "C:\Users\fra\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\gradio\route_utils.py", line 226, in call_process_api
    output = await app.get_blocks().process_api(
  File "C:\Users\fra\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\gradio\utils.py", line 855, in __exit__
    matplotlib.use(self._original_backend)
  File "C:\Users\fra\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1276, in use
    plt.switch_backend(name)
  File "C:\Users\fra\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 343, in switch_backend
    canvas_class = module.FigureCanvas
AttributeError: module 'backend_interagg' has no attribute 'FigureCanvas'
```

However, subsequent queries work fine:

[image]

Why does the first query error while subsequent queries work fine? I use Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Created a new env in anaconda, installed `python 3.8.18`, it worked for me